# Directive passed value empty and async data loading only working after second click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that should display some listed dates that belong to the element that uses the directive. So I want to pass down the elements database id and then load the data within the directive. I have two problems with that:

1) the element id doesn't get passed down for some reason, the variable stays emtpy within the directive (it is NOT empty outside of it, I checked that)

2) the async data loading (tested with fixed pubId value) only works after I click the button for the second time, not on the first time...

```
<date-list pubId="pub.id"></date-list>
```

directive js:

```
app.directive('dateList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            pubId: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/dateList.html',
        controller: function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.dates = [];
            $scope.firstClick = true;
            $scope.loadDates = function(pubId) {
                if($scope.firstClick) {
                    $http({
                    url: "data/selectDates.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: 'pubId=' + pubId,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    })
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.dates = data;
                    });
                    $scope.firstClick = false;
                }   
            };
        }
    };
});
```

directive template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="dateOpen = !dateOpen; loadDates(pubId)">Dates:</button>
<div uib-collapse="dateOpen">
    <span ng-repeat="date in dates">...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing an $apply in the success function?

Comment: ah, yes: the `pubId`-attribute in the html should be: `pub-id`, and in the directive you are correct in using `pubId`. I think changing these two things will fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you have a isolated scope with a property called using camel case you should use the parameter using a dash. Example:

```
scope: {
    myParam: '='
}
```

should be used like so:

```
<div my-param="data">
```

For the action, why are you nesting inside the `ng-click` both the function and the toggle of the boolean? Toggle the boolean directly inside the function. Secondly there's no need to pass in the parameter. Access it via the `scope` object:

```
$scope.loadDates = function() {
    $scope.pubId
}
```

Third thing, why are you using `controller` instead of `link`. The `controller` function should be used when you have nested directives that need to communicate between each other.

Comment: Thank you very much! I completely forgot about the camel case thing.
I canged the toggle function now like you said, but it still only reacts after 2 clicks unfortunately. About the link/controller, I used link first but that didn't work at all, it told me that $http wasn't a function (or when I remove it from the parameters, it's not defined). If you know how to fix that I can change it to link again :)

Comment: You are missing the $http dependency injection in your directive app.directive('dateList', function($http)...

Comment: Alright, thank you! Any ideas why the data loading still needs 2 clicks?

Comment: Can you create a quick fiddle with your actual code so I can take a look at it better?

Comment: Okay, nevermind. I was halfway through the plunker when I realised what was wrong. I shouldn't have called the toggle variable 'dateOpen', that was confusing. I need to start off with true, but I had false. So the collapse was already opened (with no data), then the first click closed it and the second opened it with the loaded data.